# How do I make first letter big in php

Tags: php, session, letter

when I echo a name in `$_session['name'];` it says "h" rnoob but the first letter is little, and I want makes it so the first letter is big like "H" rnoob??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ucfirst` function of php as:

```
ucfirst($_session['name'])
```

and you can check different functions for respective from [PHP Manual](http://php.net/ucfirst)

Answer (score 2):

try with

```
ucfirst($_session['name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use php function ucfirst() which will give the first character of string in uppercase.

```
   $test = ucfirst($_session['name']);
   echo $test;
```

i hope this will help you

Comment: Thans you its help me :D